# This code searches my database for a phone model, I want to have the option to also search by Make

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

This code searches my database for a phone model (let's say "iPhone"), I want to have the option to also search by Make (Apple). I would also like to search by price, not a price range but just price 
(£ 20, £ 30, £ 35, £ 40).

Basically, I want the code to be able to search my database by either of the following:

*Model

*Make

*PriceperMonth

*PriceUpfront

This is my code:

```
#!/Python27/python
import mysql.connector

def SearchPhoneByPhone(Model):

    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', \
        host='127.0.0.1', database ='phone')

    cur = conn.cursor()

    query = "SELECT phone.Model, phone.Make, tariff.Duration, price.PriceUpfront, price.PriceperMonth FROM phone, tariff, price \
    WHERE phone.Phone_ID = price.Phone_ID AND tariff.Tariff_ID = price.Tariff_ID \
    AND phone.Model LIKE '%" + Model + "%'"

    cur.execute(query)

    Model = "device"

    print "This " + Model + " has the following tariffs:"
    for (Model, Make, Duration, PriceUpfront, PriceperMonth) in cur.fetchall():
        print (Make + " ") + Model + " (Duration of the Contract: " + Duration + ")" +  " (Price Upfront: " + PriceUpfront + ")" + " (Price per Month: " + PriceperMonth + ")"
    print ""

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

SearchPhoneByPhone('iPhone')
```

It returns the results:

```
This device has the following tariffs:
Apple iPhone 5S (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 99) (Price per Month: £ 20)
Apple iPhone 6 (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 109) (Price per Month: £ 20)
Apple iPhone 6 Plus (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 119) (Price per Month: £ 20)
Apple iPhone 6S (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 129) (Price per Month: £ 20)
Apple iPhone 6S Plus (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 139) (Price per Month: £ 20)
Apple iPhone 5S (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 99) (Price per Month: £ 30)
Apple iPhone 6 (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 109) (Price per Month: £ 30)
Apple iPhone 6 Plus (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 119) (Price per Month: £ 30)
Apple iPhone 6S (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 129) (Price per Month: £ 30)
Apple iPhone 6S Plus (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 139) (Price per Month: £ 30)
Apple iPhone 5S (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 99) (Price per Month: £ 35)
Apple iPhone 6 (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 109) (Price per Month: £ 35)
Apple iPhone 6 Plus (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 119) (Price per Month: £ 35)
Apple iPhone 6S (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 129) (Price per Month: £ 35)
Apple iPhone 6S Plus (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 139) (Price per Month: £ 35)
Apple iPhone 5S (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 99) (Price per Month: £ 40)
Apple iPhone 6 (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 109) (Price per Month: £ 40)
Apple iPhone 6 Plus (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 119) (Price per Month: £ 40)
Apple iPhone 6S (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 129) (Price per Month: £ 40)
Apple iPhone 6S Plus (Duration of the Contract: 24 Months) (Price Upfront: £ 139) (Price per Month: £ 40)
```

If I try to search by Make:

```
SearchPhoneByPhone('Apple')
```

It returns a blank:

```
This device has the following tariffs:
```

Same with the prices:

PriceUpfront:

```
SearchPhoneByPhone('£99')
```

PriceperMonth:

```
SearchPhoneByPhone('£20')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which MODEL do I change? Do I have to change it? Because Model is a name of a column in my database. How do I change it?

Comment: So, it stays as def SearchPhoneByPhone(Model) and replace every Model in the module with search_term? or change it to def SearchPhoneByPhone(search_term)? Sorry, just started to learn python three weeks ago.

Comment: so replace MODEL in args = ['%{}%'.format(Model)]*2 + [Model] with KEYWORD?

Answer (score 1):

Change `phone.Model LIKE '%" + Model + "%'` in the WHERE-clause of the query.

```
query = """SELECT phone.Model, phone.Make, tariff.Duration, price.PriceUpfront, 
                  price.PriceperMonth 
           FROM phone, tariff, price 
           WHERE phone.Phone_ID = price.Phone_ID 
               AND tariff.Tariff_ID = price.Tariff_ID 
               AND (phone.Model LIKE %s
                    OR phone.Make LIKE %s
                    OR price.PriceperMonth = %s)"""
args = ['%{}%'.format(Model)]*2 + [Model]
cur.execute(query, args)
```

- You can use triple quotes to make the `query` a multi-line string. A little indentation will make the SQL more readable.
- [Use parametrized SQL](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to (1) protect against SQL injection, (2) allow proper quoting of arguments to be done for you. The `%s` are placeholders which indicate where the arguments are to be substituted. The `args` list holds the values to be substituted in place of the `%s` placeholders. With parametrized SQL, the arguments are passed to the cursor as the second argument in the call to `cur.execute` -- as in `cur.execute(query, args)`.
- Since the variable named `Model` no longer represents just the model, you might want to change it to some other variable name, such as `keyword` or `search_term`.
- The [PEP8 style-guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) also recommends that function and variable names be lower_cased so that they are easily distinguished from class names which are CamelCased.
- Use [str.format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) can make your strings easier to read.

So putting it all together, you might end up with something like:

```
import mysql.connector

def SearchPhoneByPhone(search_term):

    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', host='127.0.0.1', database ='phone')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    query = """SELECT phone.Model, phone.Make, tariff.Duration, price.PriceUpfront, 
                      price.PriceperMonth 
               FROM phone, tariff, price 
               WHERE phone.Phone_ID = price.Phone_ID 
                   AND tariff.Tariff_ID = price.Tariff_ID 
                   AND (phone.Model LIKE %s
                        OR phone.Make LIKE %s
                        OR price.PriceperMonth = %s)"""
    args = ['%{}%'.format(search_term)]*2 + [search_term]
    cur.execute(query, args)

    fmt = '{} {} (Duration of the Contract: {}) (Price Upfront: {}) (Price per Month:{})'
    print "This device has the following tariffs:"
    for (model, make, duration, price_up_front, price_per_month) in cur.fetchall():
        print fmt.format(model, make, duration, price_up_front, price_per_month)
    print ""

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

SearchPhoneByPhone('iPhone')
```

Comment: When you say `def SearchPhoneByPhone(Model)`, `Model` becomes a local variable in the `SearchPhoneByPhone` function. This local variable *in the Python code* would be better named something else such as `search_term` to (1) more accurately describe what the variable represents, and (2) to disambiguate it from the database column name.

Comment: So, it stays as def SearchPhoneByPhone(Model) and replace every Model in the module with search_term? or change it to def SearchPhoneByPhone(search_term)?

Comment: so replace MODEL in args = ['%{}%'.format(Model)]*2 + [Model] with KEYWORD?

Comment: Yes. You've identified the one line that would be affected by the variable name change.

Comment: It became too complicated and returned with a lot of errors, it's okay. Thanks anyway.